# Splitting line effect when the cursor crosses the line in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do a simple effect by splitting a line animation when a single or multiple touch pointers are crossing the line. (When there are multiple, the space between splitted lines will be determined by the two pointers from the edge). But I really don't know where to start. What tool I can use? How to do that?

I found some good information about that, but still nothing concrete.

[SkiaSharp Graphics in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/)

[How to animate line gradually growing from starting point to ending point](https://smdaudhilbe.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/how-to-animate-line-gradually-growing-from-starting-point-to-ending-point/comment-page-1/)

[Handle multi-touch gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi#java)

[image]>

Platform: `Xamarin.Forms`

OS: `Android`

UPDATE:

By using the sample from [SkiaSharp Lines and Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/paths/), I tried to draw a simple horizontal line, and then with `CanvasView` to draw a `Path` that will cross the line.
What I try to do now and still don't know how>

----->To make the path transparent. When the `DrawPath` is crossing the line, respective line must be splitted for 1 second(doesn't matter how much), to be able to see the crossing effect.

-----> Set the `DrawPath` as foreground on line. Now is on the background of the line.
That's the simplest way I had found. More complex was really to split one line in two moving lines, as a market door, but I don't know how to do that.

`PulsatingEllipsePage.xaml.cs`

```
#pragma warning disable 4014        // suppress warning about not using await on AnimationLoop

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TouchTracking;

namespace SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Basics
{
    public partial class PulsatingEllipsePage : ContentPage
    {

        Dictionary<long, SKPath> inProgressPaths = new Dictionary<long, SKPath>();
        List<SKPath> completedPaths = new List<SKPath>();
        SKBitmap saveBitmap;

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Blue,
            StrokeWidth = 40,
            StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
            StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round,
            
        };

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        bool pageIsActive;
        float scale;            // ranges from 0 to 1 to 0

        public PulsatingEllipsePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            pageIsActive = true;
            AnimationLoop();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            pageIsActive = false;
        }

        async Task AnimationLoop()
        {
            stopwatch.Start();

            while (pageIsActive)
            {
                double cycleTime = slider.Value;
                double t = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds % cycleTime/ cycleTime;
                //scale = (1 + (float)Math.Sqrt(2 * t))+(float)t;
                scale = 1;
                canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 10));
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.Type)
            {
                case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                    if (!inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        SKPath path = new SKPath();
                        path.MoveTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        inProgressPaths.Add(args.Id, path);
                        UpdateBitmap();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Moved:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        SKPath path = inProgressPaths[args.Id];
                        path.LineTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        UpdateBitmap();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Released:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        completedPaths.Add(inProgressPaths[args.Id]);
                        inProgressPaths.Remove(args.Id);
                        UpdateBitmap();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        inProgressPaths.Remove(args.Id);
                        UpdateBitmap();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        void UpdateBitmap()
        {
            using (SKCanvas saveBitmapCanvas = new SKCanvas(saveBitmap))
            {
                saveBitmapCanvas.Clear();

                foreach (SKPath path in completedPaths)
                {
                    saveBitmapCanvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
                }

                foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
                {
                    saveBitmapCanvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
                }
            }

            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }

        SKPoint ConvertToPixel(Point pt)
        {
            return new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                               (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));
        }

        void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
        {
            SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
            SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
            SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

            // Create bitmap the size of the display surface
            if (saveBitmap == null)
            {
                saveBitmap = new SKBitmap(info.Width, info.Height);
            }
            // Or create new bitmap for a new size of display surface
            else if (saveBitmap.Width < info.Width || saveBitmap.Height < info.Height)
            {
                SKBitmap newBitmap = new SKBitmap(Math.Max(saveBitmap.Width, info.Width),
                                                  Math.Max(saveBitmap.Height, info.Height));

                using (SKCanvas newCanvas = new SKCanvas(newBitmap))
                {
                    newCanvas.Clear();
                    newCanvas.DrawBitmap(saveBitmap, 0, 0);
                }

                saveBitmap = newBitmap;
            }

            // Render the bitmap
            canvas.Clear();
            canvas.DrawBitmap(saveBitmap, 0, 0);

            float maxRadius = 0.75f * Math.Min(info.Width, info.Height) / 2;
            float minRadius = 0.25f * maxRadius;

            float xRadius = minRadius * scale + maxRadius * (1 - scale);
            float yRadius = maxRadius * scale + minRadius * (1 - scale);

            using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
            {
                paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
                paint.Color = SKColors.Black;
                paint.StrokeWidth = 50;
                
                canvas.DrawLine(maxRadius-600, yRadius + 300, maxRadius + 1000, yRadius+ 300, paint);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

`PulsatingEllipsePage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:tt="clr-namespace:TouchTracking"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Basics.PulsatingEllipsePage"
             Title="Pulsating Ellipse">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Effects>
            <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                                TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
        </Grid.Effects>
        
        <Slider x:Name="slider"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Maximum="10"
                Minimum="0.1"
                Value="5"
                Margin="20, 0" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider},
                              Path=Value,
                              StringFormat='Cycle time = {0:F1} seconds'}"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

        <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Result>

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more explanations for the screenshot? What does the blue arrow mean? It would move with the pointer wihch splite the line? What have you done for now?

Comment: The blue arrow means that the line splits like an automatic door at the entrance of a market. The one that makes the door open is swiping your finger(red circle) on the screen by crossing the line. I will show what I have done.

Comment: Have you try to get the position with the touch point? After that cover the part with the position?

Comment: I will give a try for that. Thank you.